# Javascript easy timer does not work

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval

I am trying to make an easy countdown but it does not work the way I think it should work. This is the first time I use `setInterval` in Javascript and would be very happy if someone could find my mistake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function timer () {
                window.clearTimeout(clock)
                var seconds = 10;
                var clock = setInterval(function() {
                    if (seconds == 0) {

                    } else {
                        seconds = seconds-1;
                        document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
                    };
                },1000);
            }
        </script>
        <button onclick="timer();">timer</button>
        <p id="seconds">10</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hoped the timer would start-over when you clicked the button, but there are 2 timers running at the same time.

Comment: The *clock* variable is local to the function. Each time the function is called, a new execution context is created with a new *clock* local variable, so the first `window.clearTimeout(clock)` does nothing (I guess there's another inside the empty if block after `if (seconds == 0)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems with your code you need to address:

1. You need to make the `clock` variable global. In your example, an empty new variable `clock` is created each time the `timer()` function is called.
2. You are using the [`clearTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearTimeout) function instead of the [`clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval) function.
3. The [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) function may miss some ticks and your `seconds` counter will then be off. If you wish to avoid that, you should check the current time each time the interval function is called.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var clock;
            function timer () {
                clearInterval(clock);
                var start = new Date().getTime();
                clock = setInterval(function() {
                    var seconds = Math.round(10 - (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000);
                    if (seconds > 0)
                        document.getElementById('seconds').innerHTML = seconds;
                    else 
                        clearInterval(clock);
                }, 1000);
            }
        </script>
        <button onclick="timer();">timer</button>
        <p id="seconds">10</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

A breakdown of `Math.round(10 - (new Date().getTime() - start) / 1000)`:

- `new Date().getTime()` returns the current time in milliseconds since the epoch.
- `(... - start) / 1000` returns the number of seconds since the start of the timer.
- `10 - ...` returns the number of remaining seconds.
- `Math.round(...)` rounds the result to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Just using `setTimeout` simplifies things (you used `setInterval`, but `clearTimeout` to clear it), declare the necessary variables outside the `timer` function and add a `reset` argument to be able to reset the timer.

```js
(function () {
  var report = document.querySelector('#seconds');
  var seconds = 10;
  var timed = null;
  
  document.querySelector('button')
    .addEventListener('click', function(e) { timer(true) });
  
  timer(true);

  function timer (reset) {
     seconds -= 1;
     if(reset) { 
       clearTimeout(timed); 
       seconds = 10; 
     }
     report.textContent = seconds;
     if (seconds > 0 ) {
      timed = setTimeout(timer, 1000);
     }
  }
}())
```

```css
#seconds {
  font: 48px/70px bold verdana, arial;
  color: white;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<button>start/reset timer</button>
<p id="seconds"></p>
```